# Guarda Fecha desde datetimepicker

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, date

Estoy usando `Sql server`  y `Vb.net` y me gustaría saber si hay alguna opción para tomar sólo la fecha desde un `datetimepicker` y que tome el formato de para `Sql server` **aaaa/mm/dd**

El `dateTimePicker` guarda de la siguiente forma :

```
DateTimePicker1.Value dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss
```

Probe con otras opciones pero no es la forma que quiero.

```
DateTimePicker1.Value.Date guarda dd/mm/aaaa 12:00:00
DateTimePicker1.Value.toshortdateString guarda dd/mm/aaaa 12:00:00
```

Probé con la opción de *MaskedTextBox1* pero no se como formatear a *aaaa/mm/dd*. Necesito que el usuario pueda escribir la fecha **dd/mm/aaaa**

Comment: Desconozco `vb.net`, pero en `sql server` puedes usar la función `CONVERT` para almacenar una fecha con el formato que prefieras: `CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),111)` te devuelve la fecha actual así: **2021/09/21**. Reemplaza `GETDATE()` por la fecha que recibas en la variable antes de insertar en la BD.

Comment: Creo que estamos mezclando conceptos. El dateTimePicker puede visualizar la fecha de un formato u otro, y el usuario podrá utilizar lo que configures en tu aplicación. El Sql Server, si la columna es de tipo fecha (datetime/datetime2), guarda los datos en `binario`, y los muestra en función del usuario de sesión (`language`). No importa lo que el usuario haya digitado. Si le pasas un sqlParameter con el valor del dateTimePicker, el guardará correctamente la fecha. Cuando la recuperas, entonces tienes que darle el formato que quieras.  Anexa el código que tienes, y lo que no te encaja.

Comment: Revisa [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), al menos, como es la definición del la tabla. Como guardas los datos, y como los visualizas una vez guardados.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo convirtiendo el valor a su representación de cadena equivalente ([fuente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_Decimal_ToString_System_String_)) de la siguiente manera:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

//Resultado: 2021/09/22
```